# How to check if int is greater than 1 and make word plural or singular in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would check if the int is greater than 1 and make the word plural or singular. I mean something like the following example:

If the `apple` variable is 1, it will return:

```
1 apple
```

Else:

```
2 apples
```

Here's the code of how I do this so far:

```
"$totalApples ${totalApples > 1 ? "apples" : "apple"}"
```

But, I think there should be some function or package or other way to solve this problem, right? I wish to use a short code instead of this long code.

How to check if int is greater than 1 and make word plural or singular? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, there is a `plural` method in the `intl` package, check it [from here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/Intl/plural.html).
the [`Getx` package](https://pub.dev/packages/get) provide same functionality with a `plural` method.

However, if you want just to make a simple-call method to get the plural, you can use Dart extension methods, like this:

```
 extension PluralExtension on int { 
  String plural(String singularWord, [String pluralLetters = "s"]) {
    return this > 1 ?  "$this $singularWord$pluralLetters" : "$this $singularWord";  
  }
}

print(5.plural("apple")); // 5 apples
print(0.plural("apple")); // 0 apple
print(1.plural("apple")); // 1 apple
print(10.plural("tomato", "es")); // 1 tomatoes
print(1.plural("tomato", "es")); // 1 tomato
```

In this example, I added the a custom `plural` method on the `int` type, so you can call it simply on anything that's a `int`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I have a question, what if I use the code `5.plural("tomato")`? I expected it to return the result `5 tomatoes` but instead it returns `5 tomatos`

Comment: then you can make the method gets the plural letters from the method call, like the edit I will make right now

Comment: Looking forward to your edited answer :)

Comment: by default, always it will us "s" as plural letter, but you can override it directly

Comment: Good luck with your work.

Comment: You really shouldn't try to do it yourself.  The simple version won't work for some words ("spy" => "spies", "child" => "children"); you'd be better off having the caller supply both singular and plural forms of the word and not try to generate one from the other.  Additionally, American English typically uses the plural form for 0.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yep, I hadn't considered that. Can you answer this question and share how to do this?

Comment: You're right @jamesdlin, can you tell us a better way to make it.